# Boolean on empty contenteditable element evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have some contenteditable divs which have the following function:

```
$(".myDiv").on('blur', function() {
        if ($(this).text()) {

            // Do something

        } else { // i.e. $(this) is empty

            // Do something else
        }
```

This works fine if myDiv has text entered, then removed. However, if myDiv is empty when the page loads, gains focus and then loses it again without having any text entered, the function above evaluates to true.

For example, if I do this:

```
$(".myDiv").on('blur', function() {
            if ($(this).text()) {
                console.log('===== text =====');
                console.log($(this).text());
                console.log(typeof($(this).text()));
            } else {
                console.log('===== empty =====');
                console.log($(this).text());
                console.log(typeof($(this).text()));
            }
```

then clicking in myDiv, putting in a value, then clicking away, then clearing myDiv and clicking away again gives this:

```
===== text =====
myText
string

===== empty =====
(en empty string)
string
```

But if I click in an empty myDiv that hasn't had text in it yet, then click away without entering anything:

```
===== text =====


string
```

Why is this happening?

=== EDIT ===

So I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B382M/), but it does not have the same problem that I describe above.

== EDIT ==

I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B382M/1/) to check length.

== FINAL EDIT ==

Thanks to those who put time and thought into this. I've ended up doing this:

```
if ($.trim($(this).text())) {
    // etc etc
```

to remove all unneeded whitespace, which works.

Comment: can you create a link

Comment: Can you create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: $.text() always returns a string. Try cheking the [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) instead.

Comment: @Broxzier the problem isn't that it returns a string, the problem is that an empty string is being evaluated as true instead of false.

Comment: Are we sure it's an empty string? I second Broxzier about checking for string length.. maybe a default space / tab is inserted by contenteditable browser implementation.

Comment: @moarCoffee the fiddle seems to be working fine

Comment: I changed the jsfiddle to look at length, at it's giving 1 for everything. In my page, the default length for an empty myDiv is 31....

Comment: You're checking `$(this).length`, which is the length of the list of matched elements returned by `$(this)`. You should check `$(this).text().length` to get the length of the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selector will give you a jQuery object that wraps the HTML element and not the actual HTML element itself. As per jQuery documentation, length on that will give you "The number of elements currently matched." In this case, your selector will give you one element (myDiv). That's why the length is always 1.

You should instead be accessing the length on the text property as that will give you the correct length.

```
$('#2').text($(this).text().length);
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du3LE/)